# Determining if an element is visible on the computer screen using selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, scroll, element

My main goal is to have the program scroll away from a specific element on the web page. I have tried using displayed or visible functions but they do not work. This is because displayed determines whether the element is displayed on the web page. I want a way to determine if the element is displayed on the actual computer screen. There is nothing wrong with identifying the element (using `XPath` in the example). My code:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

IWebElement scroll = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//*[@class='_3ccb']/div[3])[1]"));

for (int p = 1; p < 1000; p++)
{

  if(scroll.Displayed == true)                                        
      js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,-1)");

}
```

I want the program to see the element and scroll up until the element is off the actual computer screen, but it just scrolls up 1000 pixels.

Comment: have you tried increasing the value in your for loop? may be something like this `for (int p = 1; p < 10000; p++)`. Or even better, use a while loop

Comment: Yes, I can use a while loop, but no the issue is not the value in the for loop. The code does not stop when the element is not on the screen, it just goes up 1000 pixels, so using 10,000 would only make the program scroll 10,000 pixels and not stop when I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the elements Y coordinate instead with the scrollTo function, just remember to include the elements height:

```
var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var element= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//*[@class='_3ccb']/div[3])[1]"));

int yCoord = element.Location.Y;
int elementHeight = element.Size.Height;
int scrollAmount = yCoord + elementHeight;

js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+ scrollAmount + ")");
```

This would scroll just past the element.

If you wanted it so the element was below the fold you'd need to subtract the browsers viewport height from the element's Y position instead. You can get the viewport height like this:

```
var viewPortHeight = jse.ExecuteScript("return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)");
```

I hope this helps.